# Cannot get standardPricebookEntry's id

Tags: triggers, apex, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to write an Apex trigger and class, to update a list-price of a Product in a Pricebook, once a checkbox is clicked on the product object.
Here is all of my code:

Class:

```
public class UpdatePriceBook {
    public static void UpdatePrice(Id productId, Id pricebookEntryId, Decimal newPrice){
         try {
            // Retrieve the product and pricebook entry
            Product2 product = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :productId];
            PricebookEntry pricebookEntry = [SELECT Id, Product2Id, Pricebook2Id, UnitPrice FROM 
            PricebookEntry WHERE Id = :pricebookEntryId];

            // Update the price
            pricebookEntry.UnitPrice = newPrice;

            // Save the updated pricebook entry
            update pricebookEntry;

            System.debug('Price updated successfully for product: ' + product.Name);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Error updating price: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger UpdateProductPrice on Product2 (before insert) {
    if (Trigger.isBefore) {
        if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
            for (Product2 product : Trigger.new) {
                if (product.ProductPriceUpdate__c) {
                    // Get the relevant PricebookEntry for this product
                    List<PricebookEntry> standardPricebookEntries = [
                    SELECT Id, UnitPrice
                    FROM PricebookEntry
                    WHERE Product2Id = :product.Id
                    AND Pricebook2.Name IN ('USA Pricebook', 'International PB')
                    AND Product2.Name = 'Cabinet'
                    AND Pricebook2.IsStandard = true
                    LIMIT 1
                     ];

//                    if (!pricebookEntries.isEmpty()) {
//                        Id pricebookEntryId = pricebookEntries[0].Id;
//                        Decimal newPrice = 1500; // Replace with your desired price
                    if (!standardPricebookEntries.isEmpty()) {
                        PricebookEntry standardPricebookEntry = standardPricebookEntries[0].id;
                        Id pricebookEntryId = pricebookEntries[0].Id;
                        Decimal newPrice = 1500; // Replace with your desired price
                        
                        standardPricebookEntry.UnitPrice = newPrice;
                        UpdatePriceBook.UpdatePrice(product.Id, pricebookEntryId, newPrice); // Replace with your desired price
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm stuck with is - that I need to get standardPricebookEntry's Id to pass it to the method in the class, but it seems like there is no option to get the id from the `PricebookEntry standardPricebookEntry` object.

I didn't realize when I started writing the code - that I was trying to modify the PricebookEntry object,
but that isn't correct because the list price is a standardPricebookEntry field, not a PricebookEntry field, so that's how I have this line of code:

```
Id pricebookEntryId = pricebookEntries[0].Id;
```

But if I want to change it to be of type standardPricebookEntry like here:

```
PricebookEntry standardPricebookEntry = standardPricebookEntries[0].Id;
```

I get this error: "Illegal assignment from Id to PricebookEntry".

Thats because its assigning an id value to a PricebookEntry variable.
But I do need the Id value - to pass to the class method - it's expecting to get an Id type parameter.
What can I add to the code, or how can I modify it, to do what I described in the beginning of the question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the whole Record as a variable, remove the `.Id`. So replace:

`PricebookEntry standardPricebookEntry = standardPricebookEntries[0].Id;`

with:

`PricebookEntry standardPricebookEntry = standardPricebookEntries[0];`

However, this code may not work on `Product2` trigger while `before Insert`,  as I believe an adequate `PricebookEntry` record requires `Product2` record as a parent to exist, and it does not exist yet (see [Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)).
Unfortunately, `PricebookEntry` does not allow triggers - [Salesforce Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GddT5UAJ/allow-triggers-on-pricebook2-and-pricebookentry-objects).
You have to come with a different approach for that, [maybe this Stack Exchange post will help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98388/trigger-on-pricebook-entry-or-finding-whether-a-product-has-a-standard-price).